# ValueError: The number of samples 147865 is not divisible by batch size 512

Tags: keras

I am trying to run GridSearchCV on a TPU on a Google Compute Engine. I can train normally with a Keras model, but once I run it through KerasClassifier and GridSearchCV I get the error:

ValueError: The number of samples 123221 is not divisible by batch size 512.

My original X_train is size 185005, then I resize it to match the batch_size - then it is 184832.

So the error message says 147865 samples - I don't understand how it ends up there.

Can anyone provide a guide to getting KerasClassifier and GridSearchCV working on TPUs?